# Regex match repetition of a character OR single character

Tags: regex

I need to escape more than one `@` in a line or any *commas, dots*.

Example:

Not valid: `test@@test` `test,test` `test@te,st` `test@t.e,st`

Valid: `test@test` `test@te@st`

Next pattern does exactly what I want (it checks whether a line contains `@@` or `,` or `.` so the result is *true/false*):

```
/(@)\1+|[,.]/
```

but I don't like `|` sign here.

How can I fix it to use `[` `]` only? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: If anything is repeated, that has to be removed? I am not able to understand the pattern

Comment: You can't because you need `alternation` to achieve what you want, however I'd write it like `@{2,}|[,.]` and forget the capturing group

Comment: @thefourtheye I've updated the question. It's true/false check.

Comment: `test@t.e,st` will be matched by `/(@)\1+|[,.]/`

Comment: What do you have against the use of `|`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't like `|` sign here. How can I fix it to use `[` `]` only?

You can't. Using `|` is the only way if you want to have different patterns for `@` and the other characters.

You can simplify your expression a bit. For example:

```
@@+|[,.]
```